# Find all textfield using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jsp page in which I add dynamically more textfields.  The ids of those textfields are something like this: textfield1, textfield2, ..., textfieldn.  I have a button which saves all of the values of the textfields.  But first I want to check if some of the textfields have values in them.  How can I check using JQuery all the textfields starting with 'textfield'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('[id^="textfield"]').each(function(index, item){
       //do something with each one
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('input:regex(id, textfield*)')
```

Comment: That's not going to work without the right jQuery extension... which is here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

```
$textFields = $("input[type=text]");
```

Then you can test them individually using filter

```
$textFields.filter('[name=email]');
```

Comment: I guess because the syntax is wrong (why the `:` before the attribute selectors) and it would not help the asker anyways (or maybe it's only me who does not understand it). That's what I think.

Comment: It's the premise of the idea of how to check all the fields. Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This code will alert the number of textfields that have a value:

```
$unempties=$('[id^="textfield"]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val()!='';
});

alert($unempties.length);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vm7y7/)

If you want the function to consider a textfield only having some spaces as a value empty, just add `$.trim()`.

Comment: That returns `2`, when it should be `3`

Comment: @Neal In my fiddle there are 3 empty areas and 2 not empty ones. I claimed that the code returns the number of the not empty ones.

Comment: @Neal No problem, happens to me all the time :). Btw, I upvoted your answer, just wanted to give a bit more detail.